# TFS 2017 Continous Release with schedlued XAML Build

Tags: tfs

After a part-migration on our Team Foundation Server 2017 Build/Release System, we now need a "Continous Release" for a scheduled XAML Build (as long we need the XAML Build).

First of all, I've put a trigger in my release definition.
[image: Added Trigger]

After that, i've started the build manually --> the release works fine.

If the build runs scheduled --> **no release is created**.

If i try to manually release the scheduled build, the following execption occurs:
[image: Fault at manually releasing a scheduled XAML Build]

Is there any solution?

Comment: Might get a better answer on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com since that is their support channel for bugs

Comment: Have you tried with the new vNext build? What's the result if you are using a CD with schedlued vNext Build?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT: Unfortunately I can't switch that easy.